# Find the flaw in the attempted proof of the parallel postulate given by J. D. Gergonne

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

The attempted proof:

Given $P$ not on line $l$, line $PQ$ perpendicular to $l$ at $Q$, line $m$ perpendicular to $PQ$ at $P$ and point $A \neq P$ on $m$. Then, let $PB$ be the last ray between rays $PA$ and $PQ$ that intersects $l$, $B$ being the point of intersection. There exists a point $C$ on $l$ such that $Q * B * C$ (B is between $Q,C$). It follows that the ray $PB$ is not the last ray between rays $PA$ and $PQ$ that intersects $l$, and hence all rays between $PA$ and $PQ$ meet $l$. Thus $m$ is the only parallel to $l$ through $P$.

I can't seem to find it. I'm not sure if it is wrong because he is starting off with right angles, or something else. I feel that because he starts off with right angles, and this clearly only works for right angles, he is basically stating the parallel postulate for all the rays between the two lines as reasons for those not working. By stating and using the parallel postulate, he is being inconsistent. Am I on the right track?

Comment: I'm trying to parse "last ray (??) between...", but I honestly can't: I've no idea what this means.

Comment: @Don: I assume he means something that is equivalent to "Every ray between $PB$ and $PQ$ (inclusive) intersects $\ell$, and every ray between the angle $PB$ and $PA$ (exclusive) does not.

Comment: A diagram would help a lot for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"$PB$ is not the last ray between rays $PA$ and $PQ$ that intersects $l$, and hence all rays between $PA$ and $PQ$ meet $l$"

The "hence" here is asserted without proof. In fact, it does not follow. All we have shown is that given any point $B$ there is a point $C$ beyond it.

For example, given any real number $b$ less than 2, there is another real number less than 2 but greater than $b$. Does it follow that all real numbers are less than 2?

Similarly, given any ray through $P$ intersecting $l$ at $B$, we have shown there is another ray through $P$ intersecting $l$ at $C$. Logically, it does not follow that all rays therefore intersect $l$.

There's not need for a counterexample; we just need to show the reasoning is flawed.

Like many of these attempted proofs that popped up throughout history, it's just a clever way to subtly *hide the assumption* of the parallel postulate by cloaking it in "geometric intuition". The "hence" is an appeal to the imagination; it is hard to imagine that such a ray between $PA$ and $PQ$ can exist without intersecting $l$, but that's not proof that it doesn't exist.

Edit: Ironically, people are downvoting my answer because they fell into the same trap Gergonne fell into. These would probably be the people (many of whom were otherwise skilled mathematicians) who accepted Gergonne's proof back in the day. What Gergonne proves by contradiction is that there is no *last* ray between $PA$ and $PQ$ that intersects $l$. That is not the same as saying there *is no ray between $PA$ and $PQ$ that does not intersect l*. They are not the same thing. With a little more structure you can think of it like this: he proves that the set of all the angles between $PQ$ and the rays that intersect $l$ has no greatest element. Logically it's still possible that it's bounded from above by some angle less than a right angle, so he hasn't proved what he set out to prove.

Comment: Would you mind showing me a counterexample? I understand it does not follow. I suppose that is the crux that I shall elaborate on.

Comment: But can't we show that if two rays emanating from $P$ intersect $l$, then all rays between them also intersect $l$?

Comment: The part you object to is actually perfectly correct. The proof sketch made an assumption that there was a ray between PA and PQ that doesn't intersect $\ell$, and from there it derives a contradiction. Thus, it is *correct* to infer that every ray between PA and PQ intersects $\ell$. The actual problem occurs earlier in the proof, when $PB$ is introduced.

Comment: @Hurkyl please read the argument more carefully. The assumption is that there is a LAST ray. do not downvote my answer because you do not understand the question, especially when i upvoted yours

Comment: @TBrendle: That's what I said. Everything after the assumption that there is a last ray -- in particular the quoted passage you assert contains the error -- is actually (a sketch of) a correct argument.

Comment: Alternatively, I suppose we could just be filling in the proof sketch differently. You are taking the first step to be "assume that there is a last ray PB", and I am taking the first steps to be "assume there is a ray that doesn't intersect $\ell$. Let $PB$ be the last ray that does". I think my interpretation of what is meant is more plausible, but I'm biased.

Comment: @Hurkyl No, he doesn't. In that sentence he passes from the proof that there is no last ray to the conclusion that all the rays inside the right angle meet $l$. If you can't keep track of the points please draw a diagram for yourself. I won't clutter the comments further by replying to your made-up objections. I am familiar with the history of this argument and its logical flaws.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "last ray PB"... *even in Euclidean geometry*.

The boundary between "rays from $P$ that intersects $\ell$" and "rays from $P$ that do not intersect $\ell$" turns out to be a ray that does not intersect $\ell$ affinely. However, it does meet $\ell$ "at infinity".

Comment: Interesting. I agree because we haven't proposed that there is such a thing as "last ray $PB$". If there was, we would have to state such a proposition and prove what it means, or at least take it as a definition. What do you mean by affinitely?

Comment: @David: "Affine", here, is the opposite of "at infinity": it means a point of the ordinary plane.

Comment: How would such a ray meet $l$ at infinity?

Comment: @David: It's clear once you have a definition of "at infinity". :)  In projective Euclidean geometry, the points at infinity are defined so that *every* pair of (ordinary) lines intersects at a unique point. And if you have three parallel lines, they all intersect in the *same* point. Finally, the projective plane adds one extra line, which contains all of the points at infinity (and no other points). For hyperbolic geometry, the points at infinity are clear if you're familiar with the disk model. In both cases, a keyword if you want to go searching is "ideal point".

Comment: @Hurkyl Using such results from advanced geometry to answer this basic question is circular reasoning, the same fallacy as Gergonne.

Comment: @TBrendle: Offering such results from "advanced" geometry to answer this basic question is conveying information that the reader may find interesting and informative. I put "advanced" in scare quotes, because it is only advanced in the sense that it's typically not taught in high school geometry, rather than actually being hard concept.

Comment: @Hurkyl I see how it helped you (I was helped by the same intuition), and i agree that it is informative, but it would be circular if offered as a refutation of Gergonne's argument. and by advacned i meant advanced in the development of the theory. Here we are still on basic postulates from Euclid. (This is synthetic geometry, btw)

Comment: @TBrendle "Intersection at infinity" is not part of the refutation. It's only words that can be used to describe the counterexamples, but the counterexamples are there without any talk of infinity. Gergonne's argument shows that there is no such thing as a "last ray meeting $\ell$", but there can be a "first ray not meeting $\ell$". In Euclidean and hyperbolic geometry there is such a "first ray not meeting $\ell$". When we define points at infinity, it turns out that this "first ray" meets $\ell$ at one of the points at infinity.

Comment: (Addition: I see now that you say much of the same in your answer.)